# Reusing FactoryGirl sequence results

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

If I have a fairly standard factory for a `User` class, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :username do |n|
    "User#{n}"
  end
  factory :user do
    username
    email 'user@example.com'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
  end
end
```

then everything works as I'd expect, getting a unique username every time unless I override it. But I'd like the email to be based on the username, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :username do |n|
    "User#{n}"
  end
  factory :user do
    username
    email "#{username}@example.com" # doesn't work
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
  end
end
```

When I try to `build_stubbed` a `User`, I get an error `Attribute already defined: username`.

I could always set up `email` as another sequence, of course, but for the tests where I override the username the messages will be clearer if the email matches it. Is there any way I can set up `username` to automatically increment and still use its value later on in the factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a block to access your current object:

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :username do |n|
      "User#{n}"
    end
    factory :user do
      username
      email { |u| "#{u.username}@example.com" }
      password 'password'
      password_confirmation 'password'
    end
  end
```